# UPDATE displays error but is successful

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm attempting to UPDATE a table and it displays an SQL syntax error but it properly updates the table. I'm not really sure what the reasoning is behind it and I just don't want to turn off the error completely.

```
Error: 1
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

This is the function:

```
function logTime($time){
      $sql1 = mysqli_query($this->con, "UPDATE `pilots` SET `active`='0',`total_time`='".$time."' WHERE username = '".$this->whoMe()."'");

      if (mysqli_query($this->con, $sql1)) {
             header('Location: index.php?pausedtime');
             die();
      }
      else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql1 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($this->con);
      }
}
```

Comment: second call in your if statement is wrong, because $sql1 contains the result ot previous execution (1), but not actual query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're using `mysqli_query()` twice... `$sql1` line should be enough. Try this:

```
function logTime($time){
      $sql1 = mysqli_query($this->con, "UPDATE `pilots` SET `active`='0',`total_time`='".$time."' WHERE username = '".$this->whoMe()."'");

      if($sql1){
             header('Location: index.php?pausedtime');
             die();
      } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql1 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($this->con);
      }
}
```

Also note, that such queries *should be* executed with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for security reasons (at least).

Comment: Excellent! This was the issue. I understand about the PDO and now that you mention it I will switch. Thank you for the answer, and the tip.